# SublimeText 2 & scala.sublime-build File

Tags: scala, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use Sublime Text 2 to edit and run Scala script under Windows 7 64-Bit using Scala 2.9.1.  I've created the following scala.submline-build file, attempting to follow what happens when I enter the following from the command line:

```
C:\work\Scala>scala ScalaGreetings.scala
Greetings from Scala...
C:\work\Scala>
```

The contents of the scala.sublime-build are as follows:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\scala-2.9.1.final\\bin\\scala.bat $File"]
}
```

With the simple Scala script loaded in a Sublime Text tab, pressing the F7 key results in the Scala interpreter being loaded and running, but the script does not execute as expected. The following appears in the Build window:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java    1.7.0_01).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

With this in mind, I would appreciate your help and feedback with the following questions;

1.) Can I execute a Scala script from within Sublime Text 2 and have its output display inside the Build window after the script is successfully interpreted?

2.) Assuming the answer to the question above is yes, what is missing and/or incorrect with my scala.sublime-text file?

3.) Are there any additional resources I should look at on using Sublime Text 2 with Scala, especially in the way of Sublime Project files for Scala?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this instead:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\scala-2.9.1.final\\bin\\scala.bat", "$File"]
}
```

Comment: That `$File` wants to be a `$file` - for s3 on OSX at least

Answer (score 4):

try this build setting

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\scala-2.9.1.final\\bin\\scala.bat","$file"]
}
```

i could solve with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "cmd": ["C:\\scala-2.9.1.final\\bin\\scala.bat", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.scala"
}
```

Note that since variable names are case-sensitive, `$file` must be in lower-case.

The `selector` setting helps Sublime automatically choose the build system.

For more info check the Sublime Text's [reference on build systems](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems building .scala-files and what i noticed is that I needed to have the `shell` parameter set to `true` so here are my `build_systems`

```
"build_systems": 
[
    {
        "name": "Compile",
        "cmd": ["scalac", "Main.scala"],
        "shell": true,
        "working_dir": "<path to project folder>"
    },
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["scala", "Main.scala"],
        "shell": true,
        "working_dir": "<path to project folder>"
    }

]
```

I always set the `working_dir` parameter as well, but I guess that is not as important.

So to answer your questions:

1. Yes, yeas you can see the output in sublime after the script has been executed.
2. I hope my config above will help you with that.
3. I highly recommend that you try the [SublimeREPL plugin](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL).

Answer (score 1):

This is an introduction for Mac OS X, but I do not think, there is a big difference to Windows and especially to Linux.

In Scala you have two options.

**First option** is using the Scala interpreter `scala`:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/scala/bin/scala", "$file"], 
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.scala"
}
```

In my case the `scala` folder, I have downloaded, are placed in `/usr/local/`.

---

**The second option** is to compile your source. This is a little bit more difficult.

```
{
    "cmd": ["build_scala.sh", "$file"], 
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.scala"
}
```

Of course you have to add the `build_scala.sh` bash script file, e. g. in `/usr/bin/`:

```
#!/bin/bash          
# compiles all java files within directory and runs first argument
for file in *.scala
do
echo "Compiling $file"
/usr/local/scala/bin/scalac $file
done
echo "Running $1"
/usr/local/scala/bin/scala $1
```

Test the script in your terminal by typing `which build_scala.sh`

Answer (score 0):

For windows add scala path to your environment variable 
Set the Scala.sublime-build file with following:

```
{
"cmd": ["scala.bat", "$file"],
"selector": "source.scala"
}
```